# Exiting loop without break/return/if

Tags: c#, return, break

If you have a for loop:

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++){}
```

Now, when `i==5`, how can I exit the for loop completely without using `break`, `return`, or `if`?

Comment: You don't mention which language you're using. Why do you want to do this without using break, return or if?

Comment: language is C# .it was an interview question actually..curious

Comment: `for(i=0;i<5;i++){}`

Comment: Changing the `i` variable to 10, using a `goto` statement, throwing an exception, terminating the thread (which will admittedly also throw an exception), terminating the application.

Answer (score 3):

The best I could come up with was this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
{
    i = (i == 5) ? 10 : i;

    Trace.WriteLine("i = " + i.ToString());
}
```

...which will cause the loop to run six times (i=0..5) and display this..

```
i = 0
i = 1
i = 2
i = 3
i = 4
i = 10
```

The alternative way to "exit the loop" (in a particularly nasty fashion) would be to do this...

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
{
    int a = 3 / ((i == 5) ? 0 : 1);

    Trace.WriteLine("i = " + i.ToString());
}
```

..which crashes out, errr, *successfully* exits the loop without using the `break`, `return` or `if` commands.

```
i = 0
i = 1
i = 2
i = 3
i = 4
A first chance exception of type 'System.DivideByZeroException' occurred in MikesProgram.dll
```

> language is C# .it was an interview question actually..curious

Do I get the job ?

I would need to check your health & dental plans, and I have to leave early on Thursdays to collect my daughters from school.

;-)

Comment: Damn it.  Guess I need to keep serving Big Macs then.  Did you want fries with that ?

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int n = 0; n < 10; n++)
{
    n += (n / 5) * 5;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

well here's another way if you want to break the processing exactly when `i = 5` without using `break`, `return`, or `if`

```
for (int lowsetLimit = 0, highestLimit = 10, i = lowsetLimit; i < highestLimit; i++)
{
   //normal code which process before i gets eqaul to 5 goes here...

   i = (i < 5) ? i : highestLimit; //and here is the pivot point.
}
```

Comment: yeah that was usefull

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
 (i==5) ? goto Outer : //do something;
}
Outer:
//do something
```

Comment: @may be because `//do something` comment, you really need to do something there.

Comment: Even with something there I still get a compilation error. It doesn't like the goto being there.

Comment: Tried it but not working though..can you guy suggest more

Answer (score 0):

The question says that loop should end when i=5, It says nothing about start, So this should be valid (ternary operator solution is better, but if we are not allowed to use any conditional operator)

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {           
        i=i-4;
        Console.WriteLine("i = " + i.ToString());
        i=i+4;
    }
```

this Starts at -4 and ends at 5.

Answer (score 0):

The real answer of course would be the following:

```
for (i=0; i!=5; i++)
{
   // do something
}
```

But let's make it a bit more generic: stop if (expression) becomes true.

The second argument of the for loop is a boolean expression which determines whether to continue the loop with the next element or not.

So if you want to stop looping because of any condition:

```
for (i=0; !(expression) && i<10; i++)
{
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works using `while` and `goto`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    while (i < 5)
    {
        Console.Write(i + " ");
        goto OutsideWhile;
    }
  OutsideWhile:
        continue; 
}
// 0 1 2 3 4
```